# Website based on CodeIgniter 3: is possible to have website in "localhost" and DB on a remote server?

Tags: mysql, git, codeigniter

I'm developing a web site with **CodeIgniter 3**, since I'm working on different machines I can keep the code synchronized on any environment by pushing and pulling to/from a common repository through git.

However, I cannot do the same concerning the database (I'm using **MySql**), so *I ideally would like to have one single db stored on a remote server and allow all my machines to connect there*.

As far as I know there's no git-like tool to update the db on different machines with respect to a reference db stored on a given server, so I have two questions:

- is there any simple (and free) way to push/pull the db changes made in local to a remote repository as I currently do for the code with git?
- If nothing like that does exist, is there a way to make my local web site (on localhost) point to a remote db used as common reference?

Particularly from this second point, I know that MySql allows remote connections, but if I've well understood I need to somehow open the remote db by setting a white list allowed for connection, but this sounds not convenient considering that my localhost machines connect to the internet with dynamic IPs and I should update the white list any time I connect.

Comment: yes this is possible.

Comment: @CodeGodie ok.... so how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

1.Create a Db.sql file in root folder and whn evr we make changesin DB we should update it accordingly,

2.you can point to hosted SQL through config file in CI. so all of the team members access only one DB. i.e HOSTED one.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set your CI database to point to your remote server. So in `application\config\database.php` check these settings:

```
$active_group = 'remote';

$db['remote'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '', //<-- your server IP address
    'username' => '', //<-- The username you should have already set in cpanel
    'password' => '', //<-- the password you should have already set in cpanel
    'database' => '', //<-- the name of your database
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: I've already tried what you suggest but it seems mysql requires a server-side config update in order to accept connections from remote. If I've well understood, I need to explicitly specify the IP address from which I connect (i.e, localhost IP in my case). The problem is that my local IP is not static, so how can I convince mysql to accept my connection request?

Comment: I dont know if I agree or disagree with that. I just tried connecting from my local CI3 test application to a shared linux server and it worked fine without me having to allow any IP addresses. If you go to Cpanel and click on "Remote MySQL" what do you have there?

Comment: what errors are you getting when you try to connect? are you certain you are using the right IP address?

Comment: In "remote MySql" I have nothing at the moment only an empty field. About error messages.... it don't get any error message, the page keeps loading for few minutes then dies. This should be related to a db issue, because by just setting my local db everything works fine. My guess is that localhost sends a request to the remote server and does not get any reply, then after a while dies because of a time out

Comment: hmm.. try making the connection straight from a PHP page without CI in order to isolate the problem. You can use this simple SELECT using mysqli : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp Let me know what you get. Make sure `error_reporting` is on

Comment: For what I understood, is possible to link to a remote MySql but only giving a whitelist of IPs through "remote MySql" pane, that can link to it. My problem is that I have an ADSL with a dynamic IP and so I cannot type this whitelist. Do you know some other method?

Comment: I understand, however you do not need to whitelist the IP addresses to remotely connect, at least you shouldn't need to.

Comment: In your "Remote Mysql" in Cpanel, Make sure you have the "%" wildcard to allow all connections. (This should have been a default setting)

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a site from scratch, you can use migrations. This will allow git to track the database, because the database structure will be in the migration files.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html